# Android - Button on click shows a list

Tags: android

I'm making my android application. And I want to have something like this situation:every time when I click on a button, there appears a list with some choices? How can I do this type of list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this example:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/03/example-of-using-popupmenu.html

Hope the below code also help you to get some idea

new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.select_dialog_items,
                    new boolean[]{false, true, false, true, false, false, false},
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton,
                                boolean isChecked) {

```
                        /* User clicked on a check box do some stuff */
                    }
                })
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                /* User clicked Yes so do some stuff */
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                /* User clicked No so do some stuff */
            }
        })
       .show();
```

Comment: But, now i noticed that popupmenu doesn't work for lower versions of android, is there something similiar?

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways you can do this. One would be to create a separate activity, that starts when your button is clicked, with a `ListView`. Read the **[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)** about `ListActivity` if this is what you want. Also, you could make the activity a dialog theme in the manifest so that it doesn't cover up your previous activity. If not, please be a little more specific as to what you want and provide some code that you have tried.

Comment: I don't want to create a new activity, because it's not what I am taking about (and i know how to do that). I'm looking for something like popummenu or something silimiar, because popupmenu doesn't work on lower versions of android. And i'm not looking for a full solution, but only for an idea or suggestion of class etc, so i'm sure you don't need my code.

Comment: Code or some context of what you are trying to achieve is almost always helpful so that answerers have a better idea of what you want. 'A list with some choices' isn't very descriptive. As I put in my answer, an activity with a dialog theme would give the appearance of a popup menu while adding flexibility. I use this and it works pretty well. But, as I said, there are a lot of ways to do this depending on exactly what you want